# How to book Kaliningrad Ferries

Tags: russia, ferries, cruising, saint-petersburg, kaliningrad

I was looking for a ferry from Kaliningrad to St. Petersburg (travelling without vehicle). Many Google hits can be found, even this one

http://www.ferryto.com/Kaliningrad_Ferries.html

advertising the cruise, but not offering it. Others report, that russian enterprise RPL would offer the cruise, but I cannot find there homepage (despite using russian search).

Does anyone know if the cruise is still available?

Comment: this one maybe http://transexim.ru/en/ferry-line

Comment: Indeed. Tickets available only in the office and only a few days in advance. Makes for a good adventure...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your best choice seems to be [Trans-Exim](http://transexim.ru/en/ferry-line) that operates two times a week.

> The ferry line Ust Luga (Saint Petersburg) - Sassnitz (Germany) - Baltiysk (Kaliningrad) has come instead the previous one (valid from 2001 till 2007) “Saint Petersburg – Kaliningrad – German ports”.
>   The Ust Luga port is located in 150 km from Saint Petersburg. The port Baltiisk is situated in 45 km from Kaliningrad.

On the ferry boat there are 3rd and 2-seater cabins of a tourist class and a cabin of the increased comfort, you can find the costs [here](http://transexim.ru/en/passengers)

The [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/russia/western-european-russia/kaliningrad/transport/getting-there-away) page suggests a few more options you may want to check it out.

> Baltfinn (728 401; www.baltfinn.ru; ul Suvorova 45) offers a weekly ferry service on the George Ots, travelling between Baltiysk and St Petersburg. Passengers can also travel on Baltic Line (www.baltics.ru/bl/eng) and Trans Russia Express (www.tre.de); both travel weekly between Lubeck, Germany, and St Petersburg, stopping at Baltiysk en route. Check their websites for the latest prices and schedules.

Answer (score 8):

I really don't recommend trip suggested by @Geeo. Cabin really exists, but they are not designed for tourism - much more for expeditors and workers on ship. And you have nothing to do on ship right until the end of your trip.

Other thing is that you have to firstly go to the Baltiysk on bus or train, and even if you come to Ust`-Luga(small town near the borders, with ~2500 citizens there), you somehow must come to the Saint-Petersburg, and this is not as easy as you can think - by local trains or by bus, either way will be with changes, and even with knowledge of Russian this will be a hard and extreme trip with chances to get into the troubles.

As for other companies @Geeo mentioned, they have quite unstable schedule because of small tourist interest for this direction. So, do such trip only if you understand all risks or you have a contact with locals in St. Petersburg who can put you up with car.

Personaly I suggest you a train - it goes regularly and you can book the tickets up to 45 days before trip.

---

**Edit**:
@arney No, not murder, I think. But a fight with locals really can happen - as a tourist you'll differ from general people, especially near train stations - there are always some bad people, as in any country.

Also, as [Wiki says](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0#cite_note-16) (in Russian), there are a big home construction there now, and some workers are illegal immigrants, unfortunately, and you should be aware every minute there.

Comment: What exactly do you refer to as `trouble`? Theft, abuse, murder? Or just feeling lost.

Comment: even tho I think these are great suggestions, given the very nature of this site, I fail to see how this answer the "Is there a ferry from Kaliningrad to St. Petersburg?". This could be a comment or an ***excellent*** answer to a question about the doability of the trip.

Comment: @Geeo I think that this is an answer with main idea "No, there is no ferry between these towns". And I suggest the train as a replacement.

Comment: @Geeo I think this is a very valuable answer written by a local expert. And a useful complement to yours!

Comment: @MarcelC. I do think the same, and I said in my comment.